# Difference between uint and unsigned int?

Tags: c, gcc, uint

Is there any difference between `uint` and `unsigned int`?

I'm looking in this site, but all questions refer to C# or C++.
I'd like an answer about the C language.

If it is relevant, note that I'm using GCC under Linux.

Comment: They are the same `uint` is just a typedef defined in `types.h`

Comment: `typedef unsigned int  uint;  /* Sys V compatibility */`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`uint` isn't a standard type - `unsigned int` is.

Comment: and what does this fact implies?

Comment: @the_candyman: That your gcc may happen to have `uint` - or it may happen to not have it. It *will* have `unsigned int`

Comment: That code written with `uint` won't be inherently portable unless `uint` is a `typedef` that you declare actually inside that code.

Comment: A better way of saying this would be that `uint` is not part of the C language but rather a `typedef` that some lazy people define. :-)

Comment: @Jack in that case you might get a -Wshadow error if your compiler already provides it for you... like gcc does. . .

Comment: Is it completely safe to locally define `typedef unsigned int uint`? For any compiler?

Comment: Yes, `uint` is not standard, but its a common hack used to pass the type as a macro parameter so that code generation will not fail due to the space in `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Erik: gcc *doesn't* have `uint`. Some header might.

Answer (score 43):

Some systems may define uint as a typedef.

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
```

For these systems they are same. But uint is not a standard type, so every system may not support it and thus it is not portable.

Comment: Worth noting is that if you really want an unsigned int of a particular size, then use `uintXX_t`.

Comment: @Blagovest: `uintXX_t` types are only defined in a specific C99 implementation if it makes sense to have them. `uint_leastXX_t` is defined in all C99 implementations. And, these types didn't exist in the previous version of teh Standard (not all current C compilers are C99 compilers).

Answer (score 20):

*I am extending a bit answers by Erik, Teoman Soygul and taskinoor*

**uint** is not a standard.

Hence using your own shorthand like this is discouraged:

<strike>`typedef unsigned int uint;`</strike>

If you look for platform specificity instead (e.g. you need to specify the number of bits your int occupy), including [stdint.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html):

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

will expose the following standard categories of integers:

- Integer types having certain exact widths
- Integer types having at least certain specified widths
- Fastest integer types having at least certain specified widths
- Integer types wide enough to hold pointers to objects
- Integer types having greatest width

For instance,

> Exact-width integer types
>
> The typedef name int N _t designates a signed integer type with width
>   N, no padding bits, and a two's-complement representation. Thus,
>   int8_t denotes a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.
>
> The typedef name uint N _t designates an unsigned integer type with
>   width N. Thus, uint24_t denotes an unsigned integer type with a width
>   of exactly 24 bits.

defines

```
int8_t
int16_t
int32_t
uint8_t
uint16_t
uint32_t
```

Answer (score 12):

All of the answers here fail to mention the real reason for `uint`.
It's obviously a `typedef` of `unsigned int`, but that doesn't explain its usefulness.

The real question is,

> Why would someone want to typedef a fundamental type to an abbreviated
>   version?

To save on typing?
No, they did it out of necessity.

Consider the C language; a language that does not have templates.
How would you go about stamping out your own vector that can hold any type?

You could do something with void pointers,
but a closer emulation of templates would have you resorting to macros.

So you would define your template vector:

```
#define define_vector(type) \
  typedef struct vector_##type { \
    impl \
  };
```

Declare your types:

```
define_vector(int)
define_vector(float)
define_vector(unsigned int)
```

And upon generation, realize that the types ought to be a single token:

```
typedef struct vector_int { impl };
typedef struct vector_float { impl };
typedef struct vector_unsigned int { impl };
```

Comment: That's a possible reason, but can you show an example where that was the actual reason?

Answer (score 8):

The `unsigned int` is a built in (standard) type so if you want your project to be cross-platform, always use `unsigned int` as it is guarantied to be supported by all compilers (hence being *the standard*).

Answer (score 3):

The `uint` is a possible and proper abbreviation for `unsigned int`. It is better readable. But: It is not C standard. You can define and use it (as all other defines) to your own responsibiity.
But unfortunately some system headers define `uint` too. I have found in a `sys/types.h` from a currently compiler (ARM):

```
 # ifndef   _POSIX_SOURCE
  //....
 typedef    unsigned short  ushort;     /* System V compatibility */
 typedef    unsigned int    uint;       /* System V compatibility */
 typedef    unsigned long   ulong;      /* System V compatibility */
 # endif    /*!_POSIX_SOURCE */
```

It seems to be a concession for familiary sources programmed as Unix System V standard. To switch off this undesired behaviour (because I want to

```
#define uint unsigned int
```

by myself, I have set firstly

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
```

A system's header must not define things which is not standard. But there are many things which are defined there, unfortunately.

See also on my web page https://www.vishia.org/emc/html/Base/int_pack_endian.html#truean-uint-problem-admissibleness-of-system-definitions resp. https://www.vishia.org/emc.