# uint vs. unsigned int - Why not typedef uint?

Tags: c, types, integer, typedef

I was wondering if there are any side-effects defining `uint`.

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
```

Comment: read question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678049/difference-between-uint-and-unsigned-int and answers to that question, and the comments. They are pretty useful.

Comment: 1) namespace pollution 2) redundant repetition

Comment: If it is for lazy typing there are two things to do, a) use `unsigned` or b) search and replace when most of the work has been done.

Comment: Related though, before stdint.h standardization, it was very common to name the type `u8`, `s8`, `u16` etc. But that didn't become standard, so we don't use that any longer.

Comment: Whilst I'm having a rant, don't ever write `typedef char* string;`. For starters hiding pointers is a memory accident waiting to happen. And all tokens starting with `str` followed by a lower case letter are reserved in C.

Comment: @Bathsheba Then you might find it slightly provoking that Harvard uni are currently teaching the whole world to always use `typedef char* string;` in their fiasco class called CS-50.

Comment: Guess that explains the quality of some of the `cs50`-tagged questions then ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negative effect is stylistic, namely that making your own home-brewed types turns your code unreadable. Nobody knows what "`uint`" is, so using such a home-made type is far worse practice than using `unsigned int`.

Instead of this, you should use the standardized integer types from `stdint.h`.

Comment: The standardized integer types in `<stdint.h>` are not an alternative to using a typedef for `unsigned int`. As a matter of fact, `uint` would be consistent with the naming convention used in `<stdint.h>`

Comment: I found a solution for my lazy typing too! I added this in my vimrc:
`autocmd FileType c :iabbrev <buffer> uint unsigned int`

Comment: @chqrlie Yes they are, because you shouldn't be making such typedefs to begin with.

Comment: which one of these types are you refering to? the specified width types are optional, and the other ones are very cumbersome to use in `printf` and `scanf` format strings.

Comment: @PaulFilipenco If "having to type a lot" is a problem for you, then programmer isn't exactly the best trade to pick. If "don't have to type" is a more important argument to you than code readability, then you need to fix your priorities.

Comment: @Lundin The negative effect is that there will appear Lundin and will say that he does not  know what is uint.:)

Comment: @chqrlie: Cumbersome it may be, but correct. This is a good answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow And then there is `unit meter;` vs `uint meter;` and other such typo goodies...

Comment: @Lundin: don't forget `uint metre` and `uint metre` too!

Comment: @Lundin "Having to type a lot" is easily fixed with a decent editor. The second point is valid.

Comment: @Lundin I'm a beginner... I thought that it may be a quality of life improvement ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @PaulFilipenco: Your life will be borderline unlivable if you start using `uint`, `ll`, &c.

Comment: I think every would-be programmer should be forced to write C on a [Swedish keyboard](https://external-preview.redd.it/ZITY688ZYbK33kFnw2CWOidAhPi0n9j2ZLBZ6ktDQfo.jpg?auto=webp&s=ab1e5ea01f1701e835e7ff985867bf8973a93df3) for a week. And yes, you have to press Alt Gr + 7 to get a `{`, Alt Gr + 8 to get a `[`, Alt Gr + < to get a `|` and so on. Typing `unsigned int` is a breeze. (From what I heard, Danish standard C90 committee delegates were the reason C got trigraphs)

Comment: @Lundin: It's been known for a while that *Something is rotten in the state of Denmark*

Comment: @Lundin that's true for german keyboards as well, but it honestly doesn't bother me at all. Using an english keyboard on the other hand feels just weird to me ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie Aye, but _A symbol, by any other trigraph alias, will smell as sweet_.

Comment: @Lundin A week is good. I am writing my whole text and code with these key commands the whole time (spanish keyboard), even now. It´s a bit nasty, but what shall one do. I guess I need to find a program which maps the keystrokes to single keys or write one self :-[)

Comment: `unsigned int` can also be abbreviated by `unsigned`. And this is only little different to `uint`.

Comment: @Lundin: back in the early 80', confronted with the same issue on the French braindead AZERTY layout, before the advent of the AltGr key, I had to use Alt-123 for `{` and corresponding codes for `}`, `|`, `[`, `]`, `^`, `#`, `~`, and the backquote too. C and shell programming were such a pain, it took me less than a week to settle once and for all for the US layout that I have used ever since. Of course trigraphs were not an option then, but would not have been a solution either. Totally useless in the Unix world.

Answer (score 4):

Reading code like that is pain in the neck.

If you want to save some typing then use `unsigned`. That's shorthand for an `unsigned int` and is standard C. Standard C is readable C.

If you are attempting to standardise the sizes and ranges of integral types, then use the ones in `<stdint.h>` instead.

Comment: My jaw just dropped through the floor. I didn't know unsigned could omit int and follow ansi. :) no more typedefs.

Answer (score 4):

You might be tempted to define `uint` as `typedef unsigned int uint;` to have the type `unsigned int` defined with a single word, for various reasons:

- for stylistic reasons, because of local tradition.
- out of consistency with types defined in `<stdint.h>` that all use `int` and `uint` for the signed and unsigned types (ex: `int8_t` and `uint8_t`).
- to have all basic types defined with a single word, as might be required for token pasting macros. Of course `unsigned` would fit this need, but `ulong` would still be useful.

I can see these potential problems:

- reading your code, some people might not know what type `uint` is supposed to be, or might wonder if `uint` is defined as something unexpected.
- if you compile on some systems where this type is already defined in standard header files or some library's header files, you would get a compile error, thereby making your code less portable.

Also if you are a time traveller, stop by Dennis Ritchie's office in Murray Hill sometime late 1974 when C was described by this [C Reference Manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf), before `unsigned` was even invented and suggest `uint` as an alternative. I'm sure Ken Thomson would back you. And also tell Stu Feldman to avoid TABs :)